# How to integrate tracking system to CPA network?

Tags: php, tracking

I'm working on CPA affiliate network scripts like **Adgem** and **Offertoro** sites
for advertisers and affiliates,

In the sites above they ask the advertisers to add their tracking URL, 
and select between S2S postback or Pixel tracking.

My question is: 
 how is it all working about tracking advertisers' URLs? 
Just start point to go from.

for more explain the situation:
Advertisers need to create CPA ads on the site. 
Ex: 
they need workers to install and reach specific levels in an app game, 
how can I as a site owner track workers in that game?

Comment: maybe webhooks ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use adsvolt for affiliate or CPA tracking. This is a complete free CPA tracking PHP script. Which you can install on your own hosting and use.